# Why should I use IMemoryCache when we have IDistributedCache?

Tags: .net-core

.Net Core provides in-memory implementations for both interfaces (`MemoryCache` and `DistributedMemoryCache`) but let's assume we have a working `IDistributedCache` implementation for our application.

When does it make sense to still use `IMemoryCache`. In what scenarios is it helpful or preferred over caching data in a distributed cache?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was searching for same and found the answer in github issue:

> They have fundamentally different semantics. MemoryCache can store live objects, the distributed cache can't, objects have to be serialized. The distributed cache can be off box and calls to it may fail or take a long time so getting and setting should be async, the MemoryCache is always in memory and fast. The distributed cache can be disconnected from the store so the interface should account for that.

https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/issues/220#issuecomment-241229013

Comment: Also, it's interesting to know, that the default implementation of `IDistributedCache` is `MemoryDistributedCache` that uses `IMemoryCache` under the hood (at least in ASP.NET Core 8).  So, the default implementation is the same.

Answer (score 3):

> By design IMemoryCache interface used when you need to implement data caching mechanism for single or multiple process on same app server.
>   **Shortly we could say, in-process cached mechanism.**
>
> Meanwhile IDistributedCache interface been designed for distributed cache mechanism, where any data cache shared on many app servers (on web farm).
>   **Shortly we could say, web farm data caching scenario.**

Hope this could helps.

Comment: We have a working `IDistributedCache`. The question is: Is there a use case to still use `IMemoryCache`?

Comment: Anything in case of single process that associates to object which changes infrequently. Like pages, database/ORM(1), static file/stream, etc. (1) I think EF .NET core use memorycache for its entities, does it?